# Java 1.8 Windows Server 2016 file.isDirectory is always false

Tags: java, java-8, windows-server-2016

I use Java 1.8 on Windows Server 2016, and my code contains a test condition like this:

```
String path = "\\myserver\folder";
File file = new File(path);
if(file.isDirectory())
    System.out.println("is a dir");
else
    System.out.println("is not a dir");
```

but always the return value is false. I tried mapping, create a symlink.
I tried also the java nio but nothing changed. Does anyone know why? Is it a bug of Windows or Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I bet `file.exists ()` returns `false` too. This is neither a bug in Java nor in Windows. The `\` character is an escape characters in Java string literals. If you want a literal backslash in your string, you need to to write `"\\"`. See [Characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: And `\f` is the form feed character (according to the same link).